# Cursor is focusing on last input field of the form on IE-9

Tags: html, angularjs, internet-explorer-9

I have a simple form with 4 input fields.  When the page loads the cursor or focus is moving to the last input field.  I don't understand  why it is behaving like that.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you create plunkr/fiddle of problem